# Image Denoising with Better Edge Preservation

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, image-segmentation, total-variation

I have the input image :

[image]

and the output of vein detection for the leaf using a Gabor filter, but the output is really noisy:

[image]

I tried using Total variation denoising however the results are not good:

[image]

However I don't want to loose the fine details in the leaf's veins, so a median filter won't suit my problem

Comment: what processing do you do on original image?? What do you want to detect?

Comment: i have used gabor filter on the original image

Comment: Are you sure an edge filter is the right way to detect the veins?  You're really trying to extract a 3D surface from its illumination and shadow, this sort of thing might work better: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/687/29

Comment: @vini It sounds like you want to denoise (lose high frequency information) on one *spatial* part of your image, but retain high frequency information on another *spatial* part of your image yes?

Comment: i want to retain only the high frequency components in the image which in my case are fine edges in the form of leaf veins....

Comment: Looks like your problem *IS* hard. Are you interested only primary veins or minute ones also?

Comment: The minute ones as well ... they are the ones that are the most vital for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you want to denoise and preserve edges. Have you considered nonlocal means? There's some GPL'd C++ code along with a brief writeup of the algorithm by the original authors here: http://www.ipol.im/pub/algo/bcm_non_local_means_denoising/

One caveat, nonlocal means is very slow and the output can be sensitive to the implementation you have. You may also consider ROF minimzation as it's fast and does a good job of preserving edges. Here's some matlab code that does it: http://www.stanford.edu/~tagoldst/Tom_Goldstein/Split_Bregman.html

Comment: i tried that however results are unsatisfactory

Comment: Fair enough. There are ways to solve "binary image denoising" but I can't think of any readily available code.

Comment: This www.cmla.ens-cachan.fr/fileadmin/Membres/nikolova/ChanEseNikoSiap06.pdf might help. You could also try running image segmentation on the black and white leaf with different tuning parameters and see what you get. There's some segmentation code on that Split Bregman page.

Comment: Have tried that still results are not good enough will have to try something else out i guess

Comment: Hmm dang. As far as I know nonlocal means is state of the art in denoising. Since you've got a binary image there may be other stuff (search "text denoising"? "nonlocal text denoising"?) but I'm out of ideas.