# What are the keywords to find an algorithm that detects embossed text from a 3d model?

Tags: image-processing, 3d, text-recognition

Currently I am doing an acadmic research about an idea which came into my mind lately.  I have a 3d model and I want to extract embossed text .. anyone knows any papers? or if it is already proposed? . I tried to research different keywords but nothing popped up which is relevent.

[image: text]

The text are bulging out (by a few millimeters)

Comment: You should be providing more details, like the text images or models. Do you mean the text is extruded or how are the 3D models of the embossed text are created?

Comment: updated my post

Comment: Try "shape from shading".

Comment: you might find this helpful: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/687/29

Comment: @SimonB & endolith xArd already has the 3d model

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use 3D reconstruction and then use deformable ICP (iterative closest point) to recover the deformation map of the embossed text. The deformation map would transform the CAD model to the deformed scene. The inliers you compute during correspondence estimation would also allow you to segment these characters. (This might be similar to computing optical flow)

For reconstructing your scene, I would recommend photometric stereo techniques. They are pretty accurate in reconstructing small details. For large objects, they would not work. Some intro texts are [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~csverma/CS766_09/Stereo/stereo.html) and [here](http://www2.ee.ic.ac.uk/publications/p4689.pdf).

Also, in such cases, you could use an appropriate lighting to emphasize the text. A low angle ring light would be an example.

Comment: If only they knew you before `-1` :-). +1.